# vi command to copy certain lines to another file

Tags: linux, vi

I have a log file with thousands of lines. I want to copy certain logs ranging between two line numbers to another file so that I can share them within team.

For example -  I want to copy text from line number 1000 to line 1200 to another file say issueLog.log

What is the shortest way to do this?

Note:  We are not using vim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the original file in `Vi` and type the following command.

```
:1000,1200w issueLog.log
```

(or)

Use `GNU sed`

```
sed -n 1000,1200p original-file > issueLog.log
```

(or)

Use `perl`

```
perl -ne 'print if 1000..1200' original-file > issueLog.log
```

(or)

Use `awk`

```
awk 'NR>=1000&&NR<=1200' original-file > issueLog.log
```

Comment: Why not `1000,1200w issueLog.log` in grand father `ed`?

Comment: Another alternative using `tail` and `head`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47424/133377